# #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 161

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1136

Ok, so I'm editing some of my .sql files and I'm 100% positive I have 14 values assigned per row but it's giving me the 1136 error. Can anyone see something I cant?

```
INSERT INTO `config_building` (`id`,`buildingid`,`level`,`buildtime`,`wood`,`food`,`stone`,`iron`,`gold`,`prereqbuilding`,`prereqitem`,`prereqtech`,`inside`,`limit`) 
VALUES 
 (1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (3,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,0),
 (4,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,3','0,0','',1,0),
 (5,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,4','0,0','',1,0),
 (6,1,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,5','0,0','',1,0),
 (7,1,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,6','0,0','',1,0),
 (8,1,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,7','0,0','',1,0),
 (9,1,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,8','0,0','',1,0),
 (10,1,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,9','1,1','',1,0),
 (11,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','0,0','',1,0),
 (12,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','0,0','',1,0),
 (13,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','0,0','',1,0),
 (14,2,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','0,0','',1,0),
 (15,2,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','0,0','',1,0),
 (16,2,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','0,0','',1,0),
 (17,2,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','0,0','',1,0),
 (18,2,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','0,0','',1,0),
 (19,2,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','0,0','',1,0),
 (20,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'29,1','1,1','',1,0),
 (21,31,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (22,31,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (23,31,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (24,31,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (25,31,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (26,31,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (27,31,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (28,31,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (29,31,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (30,31,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','1,1','',1,1),
 (31,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (32,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (33,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (34,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (35,3,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (36,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (37,3,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (38,3,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (39,3,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,0),
 (40,3,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','1,1','',1,0),
 (41,21,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (42,21,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (43,21,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (44,21,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (45,21,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (46,21,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (47,21,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (48,21,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (49,21,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (50,21,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'1,2','1,1','',1,1),
 (51,27,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (52,27,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (53,27,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (54,27,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (55,27,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (56,27,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (57,27,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (58,27,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (59,27,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (60,27,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'21,1','1,1','',1,1),
 (61,28,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (62,28,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (63,28,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (64,28,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (65,28,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (66,28,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (67,28,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (68,28,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (69,28,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (70,28,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','1,1','',1,1),
 (71,23,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (72,23,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (73,23,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (74,23,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (75,23,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (76,23,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (77,23,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (78,23,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (79,23,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (80,23,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','1,1','',1,1),
 (81,25,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (82,25,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (83,25,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (84,25,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (85,25,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (86,25,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (87,25,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (88,25,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (89,25,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (90,25,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'31,2','1,1','',1,1),
 (91,29,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (92,29,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (93,29,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (94,29,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (95,29,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (96,29,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (97,29,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (98,29,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (99,29,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',1,1),
 (100,29,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','1,1','',1,1),
 (101,30,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (102,30,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (103,30,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (104,30,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (105,30,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (106,30,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (107,30,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (108,30,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (109,30,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (110,30,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2,1','1,1','',1,1),
 (111,22,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','0,0','',1,1),
 (112,22,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','0,0','',1,1),
 (113,22,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','0,0','',1,1),
 (114,22,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','0,0','',1,1),
 (115,22,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','0,0','',1,1),
 (116,22,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','0,0','',1,1),
 (117,22,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','0,0','',1,1),
 (118,22,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','0,0','',1,1),
 (119,22,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','0,0','',1,1),
 (120,22,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'6,3','1,1','',1,1),
 (121,20,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','0,0','',1,1),
 (122,20,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','0,0','',1,1),
 (123,20,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','0,0','',1,1),
 (124,20,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','0,0','',1,1),
 (125,20,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','0,0','',1,1),
 (126,20,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','0,0','',1,1),
 (127,20,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','0,0','',1,1),
 (128,20,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','0,0','',1,1),
 (129,20,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','0,0','',1,1),
 (130,20,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'7,5','1,1','',1,1),
 (131,26,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (132,26,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (133,26,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (134,26,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (135,26,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (136,26,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (137,26,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (138,26,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (139,26,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','0,0','',1,1),
 (140,26,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'22,2','1,1','',1,1),
 (141,32,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',2,1),
 (142,32,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',2,1),
 (143,32,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',2,1),
 (144,32,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',2,1),
 (145,32,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',2,1),
 (146,32,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',2,1),
 (147,32,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',2,1),
 (148,32,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',2,1),
 (149,32,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',2,1),
 (150,32,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','1,1','',1,1),
 (151,24,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (152,24,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (153,24,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (154,24,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (155,24,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (156,24,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (157,24,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (158,24,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (159,24,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','0,0','',1,1),
 (160,24,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','1,1','',1,1),
 (161,7,1,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (162,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (163,7,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (164,7,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (165,7,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (166,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (167,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (168,7,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (169,7,9,70,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (170,7,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','1,1','',0,0),
 (171,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (172,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (173,4,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (174,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (175,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (176,4,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (177,4,70,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (178,4,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (179,4,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (180,4,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','1,1','',0,0),
 (181,5,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (182,5,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (183,5,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (184,5,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (185,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (186,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (187,5,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (188,5,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (189,5,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (190,5,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','1,1','',0,0),
 (191,6,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (192,6,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (193,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (194,6,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (195,6,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (196,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (197,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (198,6,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (199,6,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
 (200,6,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','1,1','',0,0),
 (201,14,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'32,1','0,0','0,0',3,0),
 (202,15,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'32,2','0,0','5,1',3,0),
 (203,16,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'32,3','0,0','14,3',3,0),
 (204,17,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'32,5','0,0','5,4',3,0),
 (205,18,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'32,7','0,0','5,6',3,0);
```

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `config_building` ENABLE KEYS */;

Answer (score 1):

Please count values for 161 rows you have added extra 1 or 0.

```
 (160,24,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,'20,1','1,1','',1,1),

 (161,7,1,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
```

Answer (score 0):

This row has 15 values if I'm not mistaking:

```
 (161,7,1,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0,0','0,0','',0,0),
```